# Get FontFamily from Font instance

Tags: c#, fonts, font-family

As stated in the title i have a Font instance and i would get the FontFamily used to build that Font instance.

I need that specific FontFamily istance (or the ability to istantiate an equivalent instace).

Edited : 
As asked i used Winform (on windows mobile, so i use NetCF 3.5)

Comment: WPF (`System.Windows.Media.Font`) or WinForms (`System.Drawing.Font`)?

Comment: @FarhanAnam i use winform on NetCF 3.5

Comment: How do you get the Font Instance?

Comment: i get it calling getter over control i am building.
So calling this.Font get to me the font that user has setted (choosing FontFamily) but i have no method FontFamily over Font instance.

Comment: Can you assign the `this.Font` to a `var` and tell me its type? Then I would know what to use.

Comment: The font getter is inherited from Control class so it's regular Font, i navigate to the ungerlying class (using VS2008) that is the screen with the "Type" http://picpaste.com/Cattura-5ctHsvXw.PNG. If you prefer i can call GetType() in the immediate windows (but i suppose the result is the same)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95166/discussion-between-farhan-anam-and-skary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get the `FontFamily` of a `Font`:

```
FontFamily ff = oldFont.FontFamily;
```

**Update** - In .NET CF, all classes are optimized for minimal resource usage. The FontFamily property, thus does not exist in the `Font` class.

Comment: i have no such method in NetCF
http://picpaste.com/Cattura-7mnFRUcl.PNG (my visual studio screenshot)

Comment: Can you assign the `this.Font` to a `var` and tell me its type? Then I would know what to use.

Comment: Ok as you suggested i use StringMetric instead of FontFamily to get EmSize.